# How can I configure each Windows user to have unique ip address

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008-r2, proxy, openvpn, nic

We have multiple Windows users on a single Windows 2008 R2 server (Standard edition), say 10 users.  We would like each user (or program running in that user session) to utilize a separate IP address for all internet traffic.  Is there a way to configure this within Windows?  Or would we need to use something like OpenVPN or Squid Proxy and configure that for each user?

Comment: Are you saying you want a LAN and you want them all to be able to access the Internet?

Comment: I am assuming you are talking about 10 users on a Remote Deskop Server? And you want each user to have a private network IP address, or are you talking about public IPs?

Comment: Flagged as unclear, as deleted my post as I re read, and now seen it like @eKKiM seen it.

Comment: @Alchemical, please edit your question to clarify what you're trying to achieve (and also why).

Comment: Its 10 users on a single PC.  It is a testing scenario.  in theory they could be logged in with RDC, but they will not be.  It is actually related to browser automation testing, we want each browser/site to be tested in a unique environment.

Comment: OK, I edited the question for better clarity, hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RDS IP Virtualization is interesting, but it does not look like it allows assigning an ip per user, which is our requirement.

Until any new info comes in, it looks like the easiest way to do this is with proxies.

Answer (score 7):

*Under the assumption you are talking about users using Remote Desktop Services.*

Windows Server 2008 R2 has a feature called Remote Desktop IP Virtualization and comes with the Remote Desktop Server Session Host role.

This feature comes with 2 options:

- **Per-Session mode:** Remote Desktop IP Virtualization assigns an IP address per user session.
- **Per-program mode:** Almost the same for Per-Session mode but only for a few pre-defined applications.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd759263.aspx

Comment: This is interesting, but this is actually not really for RDC users.  Just as the question states, it is for different Windows users on the same PC.  Specifically, there will be automated testing software running on each user instance.